# Updating an object from another objects property history in C# for implementing a PATCH

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rest, lambda

I'm trying to implement a PATCH on Web API for an object that will be stored in a DB. The input object from the controller has all of the properties that can be modified but we allow the client to choose which fields to send back. We only want to update the MongoDB representation if some of the fields have changed or been set. We started using a Dirty object pattern (not sure this is a pattern) whereby when you set a property you also record that it is dirty. for instance

```
public class Example
{
    private string _title;
    public string Title 
    { 
        get { return _title; }
        set 
        { 
             _title = value;
            TitleWasSet = true;
        } 
    }
    public bool TitleWasSet {get;set;}
}
```

This could work but is kind of tedious and I feel it exposes lots of logic that could be contained.

So a solution I came up with was to store the update Actions in the inbound object then reapply them to the Mongo Object in a Try Update fashion.

like this:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
}

public class EditDataRequest
{
    private readonly List<Action<Data>> _updates;

    public EditDataRequest()
    {
        _updates = new List<Action<Data>>();
    }

    public string Header
    {
        set
        {
            _updates.Add(data => {data.Header = value;});
        }
    }
    public int Rating
    {
        set
        {
            _updates.Add(data => {data.Rating = value;});
        }
    }

    public bool TryUpdateFromMe(Data original)
    {
        if (_updates.Count == 0)
            return false;
        foreach (var update in _updates)
        {
            update.Invoke(original);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Now this would work great but it doesn't take account of the values being the same. So i then looked at changing the list of actions to a list of functions that would return a bool if there was a difference in the value.

```
private readonly List<Func<Data, bool>> _updates;
```

And then the properties would look like this:

```
    public int Rating
    {
        set
        {
            _updates.Add(data => {
                if (data.Rating != value)
                {
                    data.Rating = value;
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });
        }
    }
```

And the try update method...

```
        public bool TryUpdateFromMe(Data original)
        {
            if (_updates.Count == 0)
                return false;
            bool changesRequired = false;
            foreach (var update in _updates)
            {
                changesRequired |=  update.Invoke(original);
            }

            return changesRequired;
        }
```

As you can see that property set implementation is rather clunky and would make the code nasty to read.

I'd like a way of extracting the check this property value then update it to another method that I can reuse in each property - I assume this is possibly somehow but it might not be.

Of course, if you have better suggestions for how to handle the PATCH situation then I'd be happy to hear them as well.

Thanks for reading this far.